# Resuming back to an activity without restarting the activity

Tags: android

am having a two activities that interact.
activity A picks input values and sends to activity B for the user to confirm input before submitting. activity B should allow the user to go back to activity A to edit input values if required or submit the values if they are ok. If user submits values, activity A should be finished and if he edits, then he goes back to activity A.

I have used `startActivityForResult()` and `setResult()` methods to kill the activity A when the user submits the values that has worked perfectly, but when i click the edit button to return to activity A, it call the activity A using a new Intent, and subsequently, it starts the activity A, yet previously started activity A is still running . what i want is to resume the activity A where it was left with the existing values before activity B started on click of the back button. How do i achieve this?? Your assistance is highly appreciated

Comment: Take a look at the accepted solution to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835398/why-does-heap-memory-increase-when-re-launching-an-activity

Answer (score 4):

Call `finish()` in Activity B when you need to edit. There is no need to fire an intent that creates new instance of Activity A. It will resume Activity A.

Comment: Great Rasel, that was way too easy...maybe i needed to reason out well with that..Thanks anyway..i really appreciate